# How can I remove text between two characters with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to know how can I remove everything between the "<" and the ">" of this expression:

```
i`<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000
```

The result could be like this:

```
i-1.00000000
```

I tried to use awk but I can only remove the right of ">" or the left of part

```
awk -F '>' '{print $2}'
```

Best regards

Comment: but you also removed the `\`` as well as whitespaces after `>` in the output? and several `0`s too

Comment: Is the tick ` after the i a typo?

Comment: Removing `everything between the "<" and the ">"` does not turn ```i`<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000``` into `i-1.00000000`. Please [edit] your question to either fix the statement of your requirements or fix the example, whichever is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe your data through `sed`:

```
... | sed -e 's/<.*>//'
```

The regular expression matches a "`<`", followed by any number of any character, followed by a "`>`", and replaces it with an empty string "`//`".

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sed`:

```bsh
$ echo 'i<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000' | sed 's/<[^-]*//'
i-1.0000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex as `FS` for `awk`, and print the fields whose precede and follow the match:

```
echo 'i<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000' | awk -F'<[^>]*> *' '{print $1 $2}'
```

Comment: I would like to know how to apply this command as a pattern because I have a file with many lines like my question ? How can i do that ? thank you

Comment: @Rosarionight you should ask it in another questions and show a sample of the file there.  Otherwise this become a chameleon questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'i<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000' |perl -pe 's/<.*>//;s/\s+/ /'
```

:)