# Apply echo as a pattern

Tags: text-processing

You [taught me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/690241/22222) how to remove something between `<>`, using this command:

```
 echo 'i<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000' | sed 's/<[^-]*//'
```

That gives me `i-1.000000000 as` as I asked, but in my text file I have many lines like this:

```
<    1|   |    1>       1.7320508075689
<    1|   |    1>       1.0000000000000
<    1|   |    1>       1.0000000000000
I<    1|   |    1>      -1.0000000000000
<    1|   |    1>       1.0000000000000
```

So I would like to apply this command as a pattern to delete all `<..>` in my file.

Comment: Regarding `You taught me how to remove something between <>` - that's not at all what the sed command you show, `sed 's/<[^-]*//'`, does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed 's/<[^-]*//'` actually removes everything from the `<` up to (but not including) the `-`.

To really remove everything from `<` to the next `>`, you go

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//'
```

You probably would have figured this out by yourself, so I suppose you don't understand the regular expression syntax here. `[^>]` matches any character but `>`.

Finally, you can run a `sed` command on a file directly, just give the path to the file as an argument. So, to run the above on a file called `foo.txt`, you would do:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//' foo.txt
```

And, to make the command actually change the file, use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/<[^>]*>//' foo.txt
```

The original file will be renamed to `foo.txt.bak`.

Comment: I would like to know to do the same thing but keep the number in the <> so just delete < | >  but we keep the numbers

Comment: So `< 1|   |  1>   1.00` would become `111.00`?